# Adding new rows to a table in HTML

Tags: html, html-table, dart

I've been playing with Dart, and I love it but right now I am feeling a little dumb.

I am trying to add new rows to a table in a html page that have this structure:

```
<table>
   <thead>
   ...
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   ...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that when I execute the code, the new row appears after the tbody tag and then I lose the CSS style.

I am doing like this:

```
TableElement myTable = query('#tabTest');
TableRowElement newLine = new TableRowElement();  
newLine.insertCell(0).text = "9";
newLine.insertCell(1).text = "aaa";
newLine.insertCell(2).text = "bbb";
newLine.insertCell(3).text = "ccc";
myTable.nodes.add(newLine);
```

is this wrong? What should I do so the new line goes inside the tbody tag ?
Can somebody point me to an example?

Comment: Did you try something like `TableElement myTableBody = ('#tabTestBody'); ... myTableBody.nodes.add(newLine);`?

Comment: i did, but it goes after the tbody.

Comment: i have the answer, but looks like i will have to wait 8 hours to post it

Comment: this will do it
TableElement myTable = query('#tabTest');
TableRowElement newLine = myTable.insertRow(myTable.rows.length);
newLine.insertCell(0).text = "9";
.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the result i wanted by doing this:

```
TableElement myTable = query('#tabTest');
// add at the end
TableRowElement newLine = myTable.insertRow(myTable.rows.length); 
newLine.insertCell(0).text = "9";
newLine.insertCell(1).text = "aaa";
newLine.insertCell(2).text = "bbb";
newLine.insertCell(3).text = "ccc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply this change to your hosting HTML file:

```
<table id="tabTest">
   <thead>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tbody">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and this change to your Dart code:

```
//  TableElement myTable = query('#tabTest');
  var myTable = query('#tbody');
  TableRowElement newLine = new TableRowElement();
  newLine.insertCell(0).text = "9";
  newLine.insertCell(1).text = "aaa";
  newLine.insertCell(2).text = "bbb";
  newLine.insertCell(3).text = "ccc";
  myTable.nodes.add(newLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dart offers many ways to construct elements.  You could do something like this:

```
void TableElement makeTable(List<String> ofStuff){
   final s = new StringBuffer();

   s.add('<table>');
   s.add('<thead></thead>');
   for(final stuff in ofStuff){
      s.add('<tr><td>${stuff}</td></tr>');
   }
   s.add('</table>');

   return new Element.html(s.toString()) as TableElement;
}
```